# How to use react leaflet with custom vector tiles

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, vector-tiles

I have created a vector tile servie. The API is as follows.

```
https://api.ellipsis-drive.com/v3/path/32b10f2e-3d75-45f5-aa15-92eff37a5ba9/vector/timestamp/d169b398-6f61-4392-89cb-9fdf7ec51732/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}?style=2f767421-5bf1-41ec-8e0b-7b4b27b68a96
```

Each zyx combination returns a protobuf (as I believe is the standard). I wanted to render this in react-leaflet and tried the following:

```
<MapContainer>
 <VectorTileLayer url="https://api.ellipsis-drive.com/v3/path/32b10f2e-3d75-45f5-aa15-92eff37a5ba9/vector/timestamp/d169b398-6f61-4392-89cb-9fdf7ec51732/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}?style=2f767421-5bf1-41ec-8e0b-7b4b27b68a96" />
</MapContainer>
```

Unfortunately this does not render the layer.

In the network tab I notice that this code produces an API call

```
https://api.ellipsis-drive.com/v3/path/32b10f2e-3d75-45f5-aa15-92eff37a5ba9/vector/timestamp/d169b398-6f61-4392-89cb-9fdf7ec51732/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}?style=2f767421-5bf1-41ec-8e0b-7b4b27b68a96
```

With z, x and y not filled in. This predictably returns a 400, as it is supposed to fill in the correct z, x and y based on the view port.

Am I using this package the wrong way? Does anyone have an example for react-leaflet using an /{z}/{x}/{y} structure?